# ovirt self-hosted engine High Availability

Tags: high-availability, ovirt

I now install a hosted engine on our machine.

What we want is if the engine-Vm shutdown,it will migrate to another host and start it's function.

But the engine-VM can not set the High Availability function.

If I want to set High Availability function it will say "VM cannot be set highly available when hosted engine is used".

Is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hosted engine VM is by default highly available. All you need is to have multiple hosts enabled for hosted engine, and, as best practice, enabled and working power management

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

I test the self-hosted engine HA function is OK,but I now have a qustion.

If the host shutdown ,the engine-VM will auto migrate to another host .

But other VM run on the host can not migrate,they will reboot on another host.

Do these VM can not set auto migrate?

The version of ovirt is 4.1.

Comment: if the host shuts down, the engine gets restarted on another host, detects a down host via vdsm, fences it and starts the VM on other hosts